# How to make axios call one after the other in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, user-interface, axios

Ho to call axios after execution of one event call another axios to get the latest status

onHandleDeactivate I want deactivate particular ID from UI, and after successfully deactivated I have to get the latest status for that id like 'deactivated' to get that I need to call /get API.

Note: I don't want reload/refresh the page to get the status for that id. But I can make axios /get call to get the latest status.

How can we achieve this?

1. First call /deactivate Axios
2. and then call /get to get the latest status for that Id

Right now with the below code it's not deactivating it's just calling /get axios. not the /deactivate

```
onHandleDeactivate = () => {
    let payLoad = {
      "Id": this.state.Id,      
    };
    axios.post('/deactivate', payLoad).then((response) => {
      this.closeDeactivateModal()
      this.setState({ successMessage: `Deactivated successfully.` });    
    }).catch(error => {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message })
    }),
    axios.get('/get').then((response) => {
       this.setState({ result: response });
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.setState({ message: error.message}) 
    })
  }
```

Comment: You should move the second `axios.get` inside the prior's success function. alternatively, you could mark `onHandleDeactivate` as `async` and use `await` for a more readable code

Comment: Make a function for axios.get and call that function after you get the axios.post response.

Comment: can someone help me with example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use async await for that, or move your second request into then({...})

please read [async await reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-async-functions)

this one example using async await

```js
onHandleDeactivate = async () => {
  let payLoad = {
    Id: this.state.Id,
  }
  try {

    // first call
    let response = await axios.post('/deactivate', payLoad)
    this.closeDeactivateModal()
    this.setState({ successMessage: `Deactivated successfully.` })

    // second call
    try {
      let result = await axios.get('/get')
      this.setState({ result: result })
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ message: error.message })
    }

  } catch (error) {
    this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message })
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you all, created function for axios.get and called that function after /deactivate response worked for me.

Comment: hi @userrj_vj_051620, can you mark this one as the true answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could make you call in another `.then` in order to wait for the first call.

```
   onHandleDeactivate = () => {
        let payLoad = {
          "Id": this.state.Id,      
        };
        axios.post('/deactivate', payLoad).then((response) => {
          this.closeDeactivateModal()
          this.setState({ successMessage: `Deactivated successfully.` });    
        })
        .then(() => {
           axios.get('/get').then((response) => {
             this.setState({ result: response });
           }).catch((error) => {
             this.setState({ message: error.message}) 
           })
        }).catch(error => {
          this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message })
        }),
      
     }
```